# Cookie not getting persisted in IE 11

Tags: rest, internet-explorer, cookies, jetty, jax-rs

cookie is not getting persisted in IE only(works fine in chrome and FireFox).

On login request I am creating new cookie and issuing the same to client in Response header, which is visible in browser as well.

But on successive request from client to server the cookie is not appending to the request header.I doubt that cookie is not at all persisting in IE , because in browser if I run "document.cookie" I am getting empty String ("").

Creating new cookie using javax

cookie = new NewCookie(JSESSIONID, UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "/context","", "", -1, false);

container : Jetty

IE version : 11

Please guide me on this, any pointer is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Are you sure you haven't disabled cookies in IE ?

Comment: yes, cookies are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the cookie persistence functionality to work as expected in IE11 I found that I had to use the toGMTString() method (I tried both toGMTString() and toUTCString()) for the expires field when creating the cookie. Before adding this, the cookie would not persist after the browser was closed.

Example:

`var expiryDate = new Date();
expiryDate.setTime(expiryDate.getTime() + (3650 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
document.cookie = 'name=value' + '; expires=' + expiryDate.toGMTString() + ';path=/';`